# Is merge statement available in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to use `INSERT` and `UPDATE` in single query. For that SQL having `MERGE` statement.

Is `MERGE` statement supported in MySQL. If supported, please provide sample.

Comment: MySQL supports the use of INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax[2] which can be used to achieve a similar effect with the limitation that the join between target and source has to be made only on PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraints, which is not required in the ANSI/ISO standard. It also supports REPLACE INTO syntax,[3] which first attempts an insert, and if that fails, deletes the row, if exists, and then inserts the new one.

Comment: Is it possible to proceed without primary key or unique key?.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`MERGE` is not supported by MySQL, However, there is other possible way of doing the same:

[INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

> If you specify the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option in the INSERT
>   statement and the new row causes a duplicate value in the UNIQUE or
>   PRIMARY KEY index, MySQL performs an update to the old row based on
>   the new values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to add where condition in that statement.Please provide sample with WHERE condition.

Comment: No, you can't use WHERE condition in the update portion of the query in this case. Alternatively, you can use IF statements.

Comment: Worth noting that this doesnt do everything that merge does - for example if you have a record that should be removed, there is no `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET DELETE;`

Comment: If you know the exact answer, please can you make a proper answer that shows the full command?

Comment: The way this is written seems to imply the duplication of values after the `UPDATE` keyword is not required.