# MySQL equivalent for MERGE on MATCH

Tags: mysql

I have the following MS SQL query:

```
    MERGE drivessold as T USING specs as S ON
    drivessold.SKU = specs.SKU_num
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
    drivessold.color = specs.color, 
    drivessold.speed = specs.speed;
```

How do I perform a similar query in mySQL?

**Note:** the SKU and SKU_num are not the keys in the table (this is unique).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is merge statement available in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663074/is-merge-statement-available-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql you need join for this operation

```
UPDATE drivessold 
JOIN specs ON drivessold.SKU = specs.SKU_num
SET drivessold.color = specs.color, 
drivessold.speed = specs.speed;
```