# mysql if userid exist then INSERT else update

Tags: mysql

i have a mysql table with columns like this

```
id
userid
userName
role
```

**id** is primary key,  **userid** is unique

so i want to insert data to mysql from phplike this

if **userid**(in this case **11**) is not in the db

```
INSERT INTO tblName (userid,userName,role) VALUES ('11','name','admin')
```

if this **userid** is exist in db then  update  username and role

```
UPDATE tblName SET userName = 'name', role = 'admin' WHERE userid=11;
```

Comment: See this question for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42663074/430567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO users (userid,userName,role,userPassword,device) VALUES ('11','21','31','41','51') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE role='0'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case query will be:

```
INSERT INTO tblName (userid, userName, role) VALUES ('11', 'name', 'admin')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE userName = 'name', role = 'admin';
```