# How to use UPDATE in INSERT SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I want to insert records from table2 to table1. I need to replace the records if a duplicate in the primary key is found. The primary key of a type `string`.

So my statement look like (`name` is primary key and it is a `string`. Duplicate rows can arise from `table2`, which I want to update):

```
INSERT INTO `myscheme1`.`table1`
(`table1`.`name`,
    `table1`.`id`,
    `table1`.`history`)

SELECT `table2`.`name`,
    `table2`.`id`,
    `table2`.`history`
FROM `myscheme2`.`table2`;
```

Where to add `UPDATE`? If I can not use `UPDATE`, can you clarify how to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Because I do not get how to apply it? I do not know the new string of the primary key that I should update the old one with (it is being read by the command and I have many duplicate cases). So this [example:](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/) below assumes I know what is the new value that I should input if a duplicate happens.

I prefer to use `UPDATE` so it replaces the old record with the new automatically.

```
INSERT INTO 
   devices(name) 
VALUES 
   ('Printer') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = 'Printer';
```

Can you please show me how to edit my command syntax if I want to use `UPDATE` or `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?

Comment: That `ON DUPLICATE` makes no sense. You're setting it to what it's already set to. Why not `INSERT IGNORE INTO` to just ignore the problem?

Comment: Possible solution... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663074/is-merge-statement-available-in-mysql

Comment: @tadman IGNORE has caused me problems before. It ignores other errors not only the duplicate in the primary key. Which is something I do not want.

Comment: @WEI_DBA  The link does not answer my question. `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;` Can you explain to me how can I do this for a string type primary key? I do not want to add +1 or change anything. Just replace the key with the new record's key.

Comment: If the new record's key is not the same, then it's not a duplicate key, so `ON DUPLICATE KEY` will not be triggered.

Comment: @Barmar  I am confused. If you know the syntax to do this for my command can you write it?

Comment: Whatever problems it caused, what you're doing here is not going to make any changes. If you can update your example to include a change, that would help communicate your intent. This says "Update the name from X to X" which is a non-change.

Comment: I don't know the syntax because I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you show a before-and-after example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Barmar plz have a look at my first command (the second one is an example from a tutorial, which turned to not make sense). I want to insert records from another table. I just need to add syntax to tell MySQL: If it founds a duplicate (from table2, then update the table1 record). The primary key in my tables is `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` the same way whether the new values are coming from `SELECT` or `VALUES`.

```
INSERT INTO `myscheme1`.`table1`
(`table1`.`name`, `table1`.`id`,  `table1`.`history`)
SELECT `table2`.`name`, `table2`.`id`, `table2`.`history`
FROM `myscheme2`.`table2`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = VALUES(id), history = VALUES(history);
```

If `table1` has the same name as a row in `table2`, the other columns will be copied into that row.

You don't need to include the `name` column in `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. It already has the value from the other table, since that's what makes it a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. I have so many fields in each row. Isn't there a command like `UPDATE` that will automatically update the record?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't. You could create dynamic SQL in a stored procedure that gets all the columns from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

Comment: Just to be sure, using `UPDATE` when loading data from a file, will update the whole record (not only the duplicated field or key?) Am I right?

Comment: You mean `LOAD DATA INFILE`? It's like `INSERT`, not `UPDATE`. It doesn't have a way to update records directly. If you want to do that, you load into a temporary table, then use `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM temporary_table ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271202/mysql-load-data-infile-with-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15271202/mysql-load-data-infile-with-on-duplicate-key-update seems unnecessarly complex to me. Plz check my short command. do you see anything wrong?

Comment: This is the syntax I used to load data from a file and UPDATE the WHOLE record automatically if a duplicate is found in the primary key: `LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/test.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE 'test'.'t1'` fields terminated BY ','; I have tested it and it works as I described. There is not need to do the lengthy process. Can you please confirm or notify me if I'm wrong. It is extremely sensitive and important to me.

Comment: I used REPLACE not UPDATE. Sorry about confusion. With REPLACE I do not get error. It REPLACES duplicate rows automatically.

Comment: As mentioned in the other question, `REPLACE INTO TABLE` works by deleting the old row and inserting a new row. This is simpler, but it has extra overhead. If you use `AUTO_INCREMENT`, all these columns will change.

Comment: But you can use it if it fits your needs.

Comment: If it will INSERT non-duplicates, and will delete the old and update with the new if found duplicate, this is what I need. Sigh!