# Update in case of duplication. Insert in case of the first time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table like this.

**Table/Animals**

```
Id-Publish-Update-Name
1--17:00---01:00--Dog
2--18:00---01:00--Cat
3--19:00---03:00--Penguin
```

Add a "Penguin". I did it.

```
INSERT INTO Animals (Name) VALUES ('Penguin')
```

Next I want to do is "add Penguin".　However, if "Penguin" already exists, update only "Update", do not add new column.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL supports `on duplicate key update`:

```
insert into animals (publish, update, name)
    values (?, ?, ?)
    on duplicate key update publish = values(publish), update = values(update);
```

For this to work, you need a unique index or constraint on `name`:

```
create unique index unq_animals_name on animals(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform an "upsert" (update or insert) you use the [MERGE](https://www.educba.com/mysql-merge/) command.

Comment: mysql has no merge see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663074/is-merge-statement-available-in-mysql or Gordon answer

Comment: Thanks for sharing this :)