# SSIS MySQL Import data from .csv check to see if duplicate data exists (Ignoring One Primary Key)

Tags: mysql, csv, import, ssis, duplicates

I have a series of large .csv files that I need to import. I would like to try and check that when I import the data that it doesn't have a duplicate across all columns in the tables that I am about to load. Is there a way to check and not load the records that are a match on all the columns except for a handful of derived columns that would be different for audit purposes.

Comment: Yes, you write a fetch with a relevant WHERE clause or you read the whole row and compare the columns in a language of your choice

Comment: @Filburt Ok, something learned. Didnt seem compatable at first glance

Comment: Unfortunately [MERGE is not supported in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42663074/205233) so you need to find some other way to compare on-the-fly. Maybe you could check if [Slowly Changing Dimension Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/slowly-changing-dimension-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15) could work for you scenario.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using mysql? SSIS is typically used with MS SQL Server.

Comment: @Shadow yes I am using SSIS to connect to a MySQL database via ADO.net which is not 100% ideal but it is a not for profit so the cost of SQL Server is not in the budget sadly.