# Update or insert db row based on non unique column

Tags: mysql

I am in need to insert a row in a table if it does not exist, or update it otherwise, but based in a column that is not unique or primary.

I am doing the insert part with :

```
INSERT INTO table (`match`, `to`, `status`, `type`, cat, rel, tag) VALUES ('$match_tag', '$match_tag_url', '1', 'redirection', 'confirmed', '', '$tag')
```

but if `match` exists already I'd like to update the `to` value, all in one query if possible.

I apologise in advance for the novice question and thank everyone for any input.

I am thinking the solution might relate to the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement, but all the examples I have found so far involve a unique or primary item which I do not have in my case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42663074/is-merge-statement-available-in-mysql

Comment: If `match` is non-unique, and there are ***two*** existing rows that match the row you're inserting, which row should be updated?

Comment: You need `REPLACE`.